# Oracle sql query returning empty resultset in java code, but working fine in SQL developer

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, prepared-statement, resultset

My Query is like this below.

```
select a.actl_empl_cd ,a.actl_yr_nb,a.actl_wk_nb 
from eng_eplt.empl_actl_tm_sht a 
where a.actl_yr_nb = (select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iyyy')) from dual) 
AND a.actl_wk_nb = (select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iw')) from dual);
```

This query fetches results in SQL developer as shown below.

| actl_empl_cd | actl_yr_nb | actl_wk_nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7790 | 2023 | 25 |
| 1002105 | 2023 | 25 |
| 52786 | 2023 | 25 |

But when the same query is run in a standalone java program the resultset is getting emptied. Im unable to retrieve the value from Resultset.
My Code is as below.

```
public static void sendReminderToApprovers() throws Exception {
    try{
        SendReminder3.connect();
        String sql ="select a.actl_empl_cd ,a.actl_yr_nb,a.actl_wk_nb from eng_eplt.empl_actl_tm_sht a where a.actl_yr_nb = (select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iyyy')) from dual) AND a.actl_wk_nb = (select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iw')) from dual)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt3 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs3 = pstmt3.executeQuery();`
        while(rs3.next()) {
            System.out.println("yes   " + rs3.getObject(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    } finally {
        if(con!=null && !con.isClosed()) con.close();
    }
}
```

I ran this in a debugger, and `rs.next()` never enters the while loop.

The PROBLEM that is notice is with `actl_yr_nb` and `actl_wk_nb`. These are defined as 'NUMBER' columns in DB. This query runs in java code if I use either `actl_yr_nb` or `actl_wk_nb`. If I use both in the query only then it is not working and giving empty resultset wile execution.

How to resolve this issue. What am I missing in the query that it runs in SQL developer but not in java code. Im fetching the employee codes to send out an email notification. Its just a simple standalone java program.

Comment: I got it right: when you use a WHERE with only one of the conditions, you get the expected results (expected for that selection criterion). Only when you use both criteria, the result set is empty. Correct?

Comment: Yes your are right. And specifically this is happening only when using current year number or week number as inputs. I mean there are columns in table that stores this year and week in number format. Strangely when using both in where clause the result set in empty when called from java program.